# Blacklist the [game-development] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, blocklist-request

The [game-development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-development) tag was added recently and applied to ~1600 questions. Since it has [been burninated more than once before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159115/burninate-the-game-development-tag-again) it should be cleaned up again. Could this tag be black-listed this time?

Comment: I haven't gone through all the questions, but I do see one user's name comes up a lot with respect to the tag being added to posts.

Comment: [Time to hand out some edit and review bans.](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13712597)

Comment: *sigh*  Time to black list it.

Comment: I noticed that -- a bunch of questioned edited to add [tag:game-development], I think all by the same user. I assumed we'd come to a Meta consensus and I'd missed it. Whoops.

Comment: Before burninating, it's worth it to go through the list of questions and downvote/close off-topic questions.

Comment: [Just checked the most active on it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-development?sort=active&pageSize=50), and it does appear to all be one user just adding the tag. So suspicions confirmed @QPaysTaxes

Comment: I've added [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168527/making-a-hack-proof-game-in-javascript#comment66466748_3168527) to one of the posts that user edited to alert them of this meta post and their behavior.

Comment: @Stijn:  I've gone through these questions and resurrected/edited a few that were unfortunately tagged.  The rest I leave to the community to tear through since I'm completely out of votes.

Comment: The tag wiki doesn't indicate that it's burninated. That seems a critical step.

Comment: Those bad edits aren't restricted to the game-development tag. The user [has also added](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/196972/revisions) meta tags to a bunch of other questions. I've rolled back most of their edits now (they were all tag edits and only one or two used real tags, the rest were all meta-tags).

Comment: Aren't all burninated tags automatically blacklisted? If not, why not?

Answer (score 21):

A general rule about tags is that a user should be able to ask a question using a single tag.  To me, [game-development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-development) is too broad of a tag to be the only tag on a question, and would attract questions that are too broad and not programming related.

I will be going through the questions currently tagged and vote to close or delete as necessary.  I will leave all the questions tagged so the community can evaluate which ones can be salvaged.  I believe the tag should no longer be used and adding this tag to questions is a waste of review queue space.  Adding this tag to [closed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49660/revisions) as well will also stir up unwanted older questions that are not a good fit for Stack Overflow, and will cause them to enter the reopen queue.  For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1413863/2415822) which is a blatant off-site resource request already has one reopen vote.

Comment: Maybe we could reverse-honeypot this; those that actually cast reopen votes against these would almost certainly be eligible for a review ban.

Comment: @Makoto I think that's too much.  It requires you to know that this one individual tag doesn't belong here.  Do we have something like this already on other tags?  I think burnination + blacklisting is enough.

Comment: @zero298:  I don't think that's too much...the moderators who would be the only ones capable of doling out these bans would know from the context of this particular discussion that this tag was already burninated, and the questions being edited aren't questions that we want to keep around based on the current invocation of what's on-topic.  I really don't see how this is "too much" given that editors should be vigilant for topics that are worth editing anyhow.